# Visual Studio Code (VS Code) Run Test button works fine but Debug Test does not

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

`VS Code` works just fine when `Run Test` button (does not matter if via testing tab (left side) or by right click close to the test) but `Debug Test` button logs this error:

```
.
.
.
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 97, in _run_module_code
    _run_code(code, mod_globals, init_globals,
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/Users/xxx/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2022.4.1/pythonFiles/testlauncher.py", line 44, in <module>
    run(cwd, testRunner, args)
  File "/Users/xxx/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2022.4.1/pythonFiles/testlauncher.py", line 34, in run
    import pytest
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pytest'
```

*settings.json*

```
{
    "python.testing.pytestArgs": [
        "packages/xxxxxx/tests/unit/xxxxxx/xxxxx",
        "-s",
    ],
    "python.testing.pytestPath": "runtimes/.venv/xxxxxx/bin/pytest",
    "python.testing.pytestEnabled": true,
    "python.linting.pylintEnabled": false,
    "python.linting.enabled": false,

    "files.exclude": {
        "**/*.pyc": true,
    }
}
```

I went through this [link](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/10722):
Tried the below suggestions, without any luck:

1. Downgrade the Python extention to v2020.2.64397
2. Include these lines into `launch.json`:

```
{
     "name": "Python: Test debug config",
     "type": "python",
     "request": "test",
     "console": "integratedTerminal",
     "logToFile": true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the python interpreter by adding the following code to launch.json:

```
"python": "your python path"#for example "/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python310/python.exe"
```

Comment: I have already specified a python path in my launch.json! It does not solve the issue.

Comment: @panos Try to submit this question in GitHub,which may be a bug https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues

Comment: There is already an open github thread which is also part of my description: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/10722